# Wordpress WPML returning posts in all the languages

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I'm working on a WordPress website that uses WPML for the multi-language content but I'm having trouble getting the posts for the corresponding language.

If I echo the `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE` variable I can see that is has the right value but when querying he posts returned belongs to the main language of the website. This is my query:

```
$args = array(
                'post_type'       => 'post',
                'cat'             => 8,
                'posts_per_page'  => 1,
                'meta_key'        => 'traffic-level',
                'meta_value'      => 1,
                'suppress_filters' => false
              ); 

              $query = new WP_Query( $args );
              wp_reset_query();
```

This piece of code is in the footer.php and the website changes language based on the domain.

According to their forum `'suppress_filters' => false` should do the trick but it doesn't. I also tried switching the language manually and it still doesn't work.

Is there something else I should try or check?

Comment: Can you include some more details? Why are you using wp_reset_query right after your query?

Comment: @HowardE OK. When I get home I'll add more details. I'm not sure about this wp_reset_query(); , By the description of the function I think it could even be before que thery.  I don't understand much of wordpress and I fixing and error in a website I didn't code. I'm adding more info to the question